Formatting Tabular with Text, PGFplots and tables
I am trying to make a table with entries labeled a) - l) with tables, text, and plots as entries.

I am having trouble getting the text and labels to be top aligned. I've figured out how to do this for the rows with plots using an answer to this question (How to align multiple pgfplots vertically and horizontally in multiple columns?), but the rows with tables are giving me issues. I think the following chunk is crucial, but I have no idea why the bounding box of the tikz picture would change the alignment of the other rows. I want the labels a)-l) to be aligned with the top of their cells.
\tikzset{
>=latex,
baseline={([yshift=-2.5ex]current bounding box.north)},
trim axis left, trim axis right,}


 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=1,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    %ticklabel style={fill=white},   % font=\normalsize
    xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    width=6cm, height=6cm, 
    domain = -2:2
}
\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    baseline={([yshift=-2.5ex]current bounding box.north)},
    trim axis left, trim axis right,
}
\newcommand{\resetTabular}{ \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}
\newcommand{\tableA}{
    {\resetTabular\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            $x$& $f(x)$ \\
            \hline
            $-1$& $-2$ \\
            \hline
            $0$& $0$ \\
            \hline
            $1$& $2$  \\
            \hline
            $2$ & $4$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}
\newcommand{\tableB}{   
    {\resetTabular\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            $x$& $f(x)$ \\
            \hline
            $0$& $0$ \\
            \hline
            $1$& $2$ \\
            \hline
            $2$& $4$  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}
\newcommand{\tableC}{   
    {\resetTabular\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            $x$& $f(x)$ \\
            \hline
            $-2$ & $4$\\
            \hline
            $-1$ & $2$\\
            \hline
            $0$& $0$ \\
            \hline
            $1$& $2$ \\
            \hline
            $2$& $4$  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}
\newcommand{\piecewiseA}{
    $f(x) = \begin{cases}
        2x &\text{if } 2x \geq 0\\
        -2x &\text{if } 2x < 0
    \end{cases} $
}
\newcommand{\plotA}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = {\(f(x)\)},
            ]
            %Below the red parabola is defined
            \addplot[<->]{2*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcounter{cell}
\renewcommand*{\thecell}{\alph{cell})} 
\newcommand{\myletter}{\stepcounter{cell}\thecell}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{center}  
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} rl rl rl @{}}

        \myletter & $f(x) = \sqrt{(2x)^2}$& \myletter & \tableA & \myletter & \\
        \myletter &\piecewiseA  &\myletter &
        $f(x) = 2x$
        & \myletter & \tableB \\   
        \myletter & \plotA & \myletter & cell8  & \myletter & $f(x) = (\sqrt{2x})^2$   \\
        \myletter & \tableC &\myletter & $f(x) = |2x|$  & \myletter &    
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document} 

